# How to find out when each user's last commit was to subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, release, release-management

I have a repository that is running subversion.  Some users have not been committing regularly.  I'd like to send out a weekly reminder to those that have not committed during the last week.  Is there a way to determine when each users last submit date was?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do it (others will be able to suggest how), but it makes me nervous to hear "people aren't committing and they should be doing so more often." I can understand you don't want them to be lazy, but a lot of programming is about thinking and understanding the problem.  They may have also branched so they are committing there instead of to the trunk.  I guess I'm just saying be careful of the reasons for doing something like this.  Programmers like to be trusted, too.

Comment: If this was a weekly thing, it wouldn't be. Perhaps weekly is too much. How about monthly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without trying to address whether you *should* do it or not, the following will give you a unique list of users who committed between `DATE1` and `DATE2`

```
svn log -r'{DATE1}:{DATE2}' | grep -E '\|' | cut -f2 -d'|' | sort | uniq
```

Where `DATE1` and `DATE2` are formatted as `yyyymmdd`.

I presume that once you have a list of users who committed, you'll know who didn't as you could compare it against a full list (e.g. `diff committed_users.txt all_users.txt`).

Answer (score 4):

Beware what you measure, because you will receive it in spades.

Two techniques are possible.  You could write a small program to either call "svn log" and pull out the relevant developer names and last commit times.  You could add a script to the appropriate post-commit hook which either removes the developer from the email list which is regenerated weekly, or replaces the developer's last commit time in a file that is processed later.

The main problem is that by measuring commits, you'll get more commits.  The quality of the commits will decrease dramatically by those who game the system.  I foresee comment only commits, or commits of the most trivial nature in your near future.

Comment: While I generally agree with the idea that you don't want to track commits too religiously or force commits of bad (or even questionable) code, I know I've worked on plenty of projects where developers spent weeks and weeks neither committing nor updating their code, committed right before a testing deadline, and caused extensive painful integration failures during crunch time as a result.  So I also sympathize with the need to at least pay attention to which developers aren't committing, so that a dev mgr can go find out why they aren't committing.

Comment: This isn't for a weekly nag email.  This is more for the situation where Jim discussed, where collisions and non-committal issues are happening pretty often, and trying to think of a way to fix the problem.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you need to make it clear that breaking the head is frowned upon, coupled with healthy use of "svn blame".  It's not a foolproof solution, but it shifts the burden of not checking in heavily onto the shoulders of those who check in seldom.  If they can continue to break the head / branch with impunity, then you have other issues.